# When trying to parse DateTime - An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two different dates that I want to subtract, but when I try to show the subtracted value it crashes with the message from the title - `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`. The weird thing is that I am using the same method when trying to display the `DateTime`.

Here is my (edited) code:

```
//works fine
        DateTime startingTime = DateTime.Now;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(startingTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

//works fine
        DateTime newTime = DateTime.Now;
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(newTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 

//EXCEPTION
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show((newTime - startingTime).ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

I also tried using `TimeSpan` and `newTime.Subtract(startingTime)`, but that returns the same exception.

The exception only occurs when I am trying to parse it in my format - `HH:mm:ss`. It works fine if I only use `ToString()`, but that is not the format I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `newTime - startingTime` returns a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it has a different formatting than a `DateTime`.

- [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I believe this will work;

```
string.Format("{0:HH\\:mm\\:ss}", (newTime - startingTime))
```

But this works on .NET Framework 4+. If you use .NET 3.5 or lower, you can use;

```
TimeSpan ts = newTime - startingTime;
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
                             (int)ts.TotalHours,
                                  ts.Minutes,
                                  ts.Seconds);
```

Comment: I think there is no other way then to use `c`. Or concatenating yourself.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't want to use `c` because it shows `fffff` part also.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Isn't that the all point? Presentation of this `TimeSpan` in `MessageBox.Show` method.

Comment: Depends on the specs of the two dates. If they never contain < seconds, it's alright.

Comment: Yes, I needed the time without the milliseconds. The second method works fine (haven't tried the first). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
(newTime - startingTime).ToString("c")
```

It formats a `TimeSpan` as `hh:mm:ss`. Since this default format is not culture-sensitive, there is no need to pass the `CultureInfo`.

Or, to avoid the millisecond problem (just an alternative of Soner's better second answer):

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Floor(newTime - startingTime.TotalSeconds)).ToString("c")
```